# name is already used by an existing object SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have tested this code on an online editor and it works fine but for some reason, it keeps giving me the error in SQL DEVELOPER -

```
Error report -
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
```

I have tried to change the names but it doesn't seem to fix it

```
create or replace procedure Get_Fact ( x in number)
as
fac number:=1;
i number;

begin
    for i in 1..x
    loop
        fac:=fac*i;
    end loop;
 
    dbms_output.put_line('factorial='||fac);
end;
```

Comment: @MT0 gave you the correct answer, but I am curious as to how you "tested in an online editor".  What  "online editor"?  Sounds like some external tool that just does a syntax check, whereas actually compiling the code (executing the CREATE statement) involves far more than just a syntax check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Is self explanatory; you have another object in the same schema with the same `GET_FACT` identifier.

You can use the query:

```sql
SELECT owner,
       object_name,
       object_type
FROM   all_objects
WHERE  object_name = 'GET_FACT';
```

To find out what the existing object is.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f9f5dd604bad7400a84c36142e70996)*